# ftp batch file log data to txt

Tags: file, batch-file, ftp, logfile

me again :P
I have some problems with some bat file, that bat file , connects to and ftp and download all files from a remote folder, then delete it, but my problem/question is: i need a txt(log) of every file before download it from the remote server, here is my file

bat file:

```
ftp -i -s:ftpfile.txt site.com
```

txt file

```
user-name
user-pass
lcd c:\localfolder\some\folder
cd remotefolder-name
mget . 
mdelete \\remotefolder-name\ .
quit
```

If i use the >>mylog.txt on this line:

```
ftp -i -s:ftpfile.txt site.com>>mylog.txt
```

I get some extra data that i dont want to. I just need the file names before download it, something like this:

log.txt

```
file001x.xml
filedfx.xml
file023x.xml
filed33x.xml
```

Ps:sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may redirect `ls` output to local file. Syntax is: `ls pattern local_file`. An example would be: `ls * ftplist.txt` or `ls . ftplist.txt`. Both will produce a file `ftplist.txt` (in local current directory if you do not specify path) with a list  of files (and possibly subdirs) in current directory on remote server (in slightly different formats)

Comment: hi wmz, but in that way will not be overwrited? because that bat files is executed every 1 minute.
in bat files i normally use >>log.txt  to save every file name in a new line.

Comment: yes it will get overwritten, but you could just add another step to append its contents to your full log file in your loop